# I've lost my storage to update the phone Android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, storage, partitions

yesterday update the phone of a friend by clicking on software updates.
The phone is a Cubot s308 and the update version is v6_cq_4137c_v0.1.3_20150721 (4.4 Android).

After upgrading to pass to have 16 gb of storage to 1 gb. I can not install any app or do anything because the storage is full. It is as if had a partition that is not mounted and I think that on that partition will be photos, music...

Any thing that can be done to recover the lost storage and its contents?

Thank you!